# Mac OS X Lion + xCode 4.1 + texturetool = forced mipmaps?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures, mipmaps

After upgrading to Lion and re-building the project I noticed that Apple's texturetool started to generate mipmaps, although I don't have -m flag in my scripts. I know that mipmaps are useful sometimes and generally it is the way to go to have them, but in this particular app I DO NOT WANT them.

Does anybody know how to switch it off? I would accept any solution (including replacing libraries from older version etc). BTW, using texturetool from old Mac OS doesn't seem to help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ran into this exact problem and have been unable to find a solution.  Anyone know what's going on?  Driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a c program to remove the mipmaps of a pvr, this can be a work-around while Apple fix it...

I generate the PVR, then strip the mipmaps with this program.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7600660/PVRRemoveMipmaps.c

```
./PVRRemoveMipmaps filename.pvr
```

edit:
changelog: 1/september/2011 - Fixed a mistake in the header field dataLength of the new PVR without mipmaps.